# How to access writable partition on Ubuntu booted from USB flash drive?

Tags: boot, live-usb, persistence

I created a bootable USB flash drive with `ubuntu-mate-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso` using Startup Disk Creator. It created `writable` partition from the remaining space left. I copied a few programs to this partition. When I boot from this flash drive, Discs shows it as `writable Partition 4` mounted at `/var/crash`, but that directory is empty when I open it with Nautilus. How can I find these files?

Answer (score 5):

### Access writable partition on Ubuntu booted from USB flash drive

The easiest tool for making a Live USB, that can be used for installing Ubuntu, comes with Ubuntu and is called **Startup Disk Creator**. It overwrites the whole disk as you mention in the question.

The useless space resulting from a **SDC** install can be easily converted to a NTFS or FAT32 data partition useful for data storage and transportation like mkusb.

**Procedure** Legacy Boot

- Run **Startup Disk Creator**, **dd**. **Disks** or **Etcher** to create Live 19.10, or later, USB
- Boot new Live USB to activate writable partition, (AKA casper-rw), then Power Off.
- Reboot the Live USB **toram**. (press `shift` when booting, hit `F6` and type a space and `toram`).
- Unmount writable/casper-rw partition using Disks.
- For **NTFS** open Terminal and run:

`sudo mkfs.ntfs -f -L data /dev/sdx3`

were x is the drive letter of the new Live USB

For **FAT32** use:

`sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 -n data /dev/sdx1`

The drive should now have the original data space minus the size of the OS ISO.

**Procedure** UEFI Boot

Same as Legacy Boot however at GRUB menu press `e`. After the words `quiet splash` type a space then `toram`. Press `F10` to continue boot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help in another way. I wanted to use the writable partition to store files of any kind but was affraid to erase the "writable" partition because I don't know how important is. So I tried to redimension the "writable" partition to free some space..

My USB has initially 4 GB for the Ubuntu installer, an EFI partition (3 o 4 MB), another little partition and a 12 GB as "writable". Total: 16 GB USB.

I used Ubuntu "Disks" (Applications / Utilities / Disks) to resize the 12 GB "writable" partition to 4 GB (with the "writable" partition selected, clic on the options icon and choose "resize...").

After this, I got an empty space of 8 GB. You must format it before you can use it (NTFS, FAT, ext4,... at your convenience). As above, whit this new partition selected, clic on the options icon and select to format.

Tnx to the community for this space to share!